# Endpoint URL and WSDL of a web service class with @WebServiceProvider

Tags: web-services

How to publish a web service class with @WebServiceProvider?What is the endpoint URL in this case?
Could we generate wsdl with @WebServiceProvider as in the case with 
@WebService?What does the "wsdlLocation" attribute mean in @WebServiceProvider?

For instance

```
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
@WebServiceProvider(portName = "ProviderPort",serviceName = "ProviderService",
    targetNamespace = "http://bean/")
public class WebServiceProviderImpl implements Provider<SOAPMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is-

```
package server;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

    public class Server {

        protected Server() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Starting Server");
            System.out.println("Starting SoapService1");
            Object implementor = new WebServiceProviderImpl();
            String address = "http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1";
            Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
            }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            new Server();
            System.out.println("Server ready...");
            Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
            System.out.println("Server exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

The URL is "address". As far as I understand you can specify it as you like, as long as the port is free.

Alternatively, you could use JAXWsServerFactoryBean which is a part of CXF.
You would do the same thing as you would with an SEI.

And yes, it does generate a WSDL for you.
You can create your client stubs from it using wsimport just like an SEI